# Unable to validate request.resource.data due to FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am getting this Error Message:

> FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions

Once executing signUpUser function

```
const signUpUser = async (firstName, lastName, mobile, email) => {
    try {
      // create new authenticated user
      const credentials = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        email,
        password
      );

      // create user in database
      const userUid = credentials.user.uid;
      let userData = {
        first_name: firstName,
        last_name: lastName,
        mobile: mobile,
        email: email,
      };
      await setDoc(doc(db, "Users", userUid), {
        ...userData,
        created_date: serverTimestamp(),
      });

      console.log("created user with", credentials.user);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error: ", error.message); 
    }
  };
```

and my firestore rules are as shown

```
   rules_version = '2';
   service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    
    match /Users/{userId}{
    // any sign up user can create new user document
      allow create: if isValidToSignup() && isValidUser();      //--> not working as expected
    }

    function isValidToSignup(){
      return request.auth.uid != null
    }
    function isValidUser() {
       return  incomingData().first_name is string &&
               incomingData().first_name.size() > 2 &&  incomingData().firstname.size() < 30 &&
               incomingData().last_name is string &&
               incomingData().last_name.size() > 2 &&  incomingData().lastname.size() < 30 &&
               incomingData().mobile is string 
   }
   function incomingData() {
      return request.resource.data;
   }
}
}
```

I have checked that the inputs `(firstName, lastName, mobile, email)` are all of the type string and comply with the given rules, and I was expecting that there should be no error related to Firestore permission.

Comment: Your security rule missing closure curly braces. Close the braces of `match /Users/{userId}` after immediate implementation And close the braces of `match /databases/{database}/documents` after `function incomingData()` implementation and redeploy

Comment: Thanks, @RoopaM, the missing curly braces were added. The problem stated in the post still persists though.

Comment: Add `allow read, write: if request.auth != null;` in your security rules and try again. Also check [this Article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404)